# Firestore Rules multi organization multi user access rights listing data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to set up a ruleset for a new Firestore project where we have the following root collections:

users

organisations

Under users we have users/userid/ar/organisationid (ar for access rights)

This document should define what access rights the user have for a given organisation. The point being that many users can have access to one or more organisation in this saas application.

I want all the documents and all the subcollections under the organisation to be checked agains this access right.

This works perfectly for get and write, but listing of data gives an access error, and the only way I found to restrict the list data is to add an array on the document that list the usersids, and also filter on this client side. This is not a solution that is maintainable for production since there will be alot of subcollections with many documents.

Is there any suggestions? Any other way I can make the listing work for Firestore? Is there better way to structure the data, or anything I am missing?

Only other way I can see is to use firestore functions to do the check server side for the listing, but then we loose the awesome stuff in @angular/fire.

Filtering client side is not good enough security.

Thank you.

Rules as of now:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      match /ar/{organisationDoc} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
        allow write: if false;
      }
    }     

    // read
    match /organisations/{oId} {
      allow get: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/ar/$(oId));
      allow list: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.users;

      match /{all=**} {
        allow get: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/ar/$(oId));
        allow list: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.users;
      }
    }

    // write
    match /organisations/{oId} {
      allow create: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/ar/$(oId)).data.create == true;
      allow update: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/ar/$(oId)).data.update == true;
      allow delete: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/ar/$(oId)).data.delete == true;

      match /{all=**} {
        allow create: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/ar/$(oId)).data.create == true;
        allow update: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/ar/$(oId)).data.update == true;
        allow delete: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)/ar/$(oId)).data.delete == true;
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are encountering is caused by the fact that "**security rules are not filters**", see this documentation [item](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#queries_and_security_rules).

In other words, your query must filter the organizations for which the user has (read) access rights, for example like you do with "array on the document that list the `usersids`". You could also have the lists of organizations as an array in the user doc.

Using a Cloud Function to "check server side for the listing" and (if I understand correctly) build your query based on the result of this Cloud Function call is really not ideal.

But what you can do with a Cloud Function is to populate/modify automatically the array listing the `userids` (or the `organizations`) when you create/modify/delete an `organisationid` document under `users/userid/ar/organisationid`.

---

Note that the doc says:

> This behavior applies to queries that retrieve one or more documents
>   from a collection **and not to individual document retrievals**

This is why your rules work for the `get()` method, as you mention.

Comment: Yes, this I understand, and the only way I made it work with listing is with the users array in the organisation document, and also filter on that on the client. This, nor using cloud functions are ideal.

Can you explain abit what you mean by "You could also have the lists of organizations as an array in the user doc"? since this is exactly what I am trying to do, and the "ar" collection on the users is in fact a list of organisationIds. How would the list rule look for that?

Comment: You could probably solve your problem by listing in each user document the organizations this user has access to, as an array. Then, in your security rules, you would either use `in` or `hasAny`, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access and https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List#hasAny. In this case you don't need a specific collection anymore.

Comment: The role based access guide does it the same way as i, with a collection on the target document, not the user document, and I fail to see how I can make a rule that works for listing with a organisationid array on the user document.

Comment: After some further testing it looks like my orignal get rule also works for subcollections under the organisation, it just does not work for listing on the organisation collection itself (seems like it does not have the {oId} variable), and as far as i can tell i need the users array on the orgranisation document. I guess this is manageable by a trigger function as you suggested, although not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

[See documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims)

> #### Control Access with Custom Claims and Security Rules
>
> The Firebase Admin SDK supports defining custom attributes on user
> accounts. This provides the ability to implement various access
> control strategies, including role-based access control, in Firebase
> apps. These custom attributes can give users different levels of
> access (roles), which are enforced in an application's security rules.